# Facing Issue in For Loop of Web Element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Can someone please help me to resolve the issue. If i get 2 webelements in the app_list ( List of Web element), the increment is not happening. Can you please guide me to resolve the issue.

```
app_list = []
app_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@type='appIcon']")
print(len(app_list))
for apps in app_list:
apps = app_list.text.partition("\n")[2]
apps = apps.replace("\n","")
print(apps.text)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@aria-label='Search Play Console']").click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//*[@aria-label='Search Play Console']").send_keys(apps)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
app_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='"+apps+"']").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
target = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[text()='App content']/../../../../a")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);', target)
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
if target.is_displayed:
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].click();",target)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
status = 'Privacy policy'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='Manage privacy policy']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Add a privacy policy to your store listing to help provide transparency about how you treat sensitive user and device data.']")))
updateURL = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='Privacy policy URL']")
if updateURL.get_attribute("value") == "https://www.xxxxxx.com/privacy-statement":
status = 'Privacy policy have been already updated'
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
log.write(cid + " - " + apps + " - " + str(list_status[status]) + "\n")
driver.get("https://xxxxx.com/console/u/0/developers/%s/app-list" % id)
else:
status = 'Privacy Policy not updated'
updateURL.clear()
updateURL.send_keys("https://www.xxxxxx.com/privacy-statement")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Save']").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[text()='Your changes have been saved']")))
log.write(cid + " - " + apps + " - " + str(list_status[status]) + "\n")
driver.implicitly_wait(2)
driver.get("https://xxxxxx.com/console/u/0/developers/%s/app-list" % id)
```

It should increment the next web element as well. As per the current code, after first web element, I am getting the error as NoSuchElementfound exception.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? It is important for how the logic flow goes.

Comment: app_list = []
        app_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//*[@type='appIcon']")
        print(len(app_list))
        for apps in app_list:
           apps = apps.text.partition("\n")[2]
           apps = apps.replace("\n","")
           print(apps)

Comment: please a) format your original question code part via editing, b) explain the question in more details, like what changes you done and what is the result you would like to get, what is the actual result, and what is the line of code there you expecting your results